# Understanding Yield in ES6 with functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I understand the concept of generators and what the keyword 'yield' represents in JavaScript but as I've played around with it in Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) on Mac OS X 10.10.3) I've ran into a situation that I don't understand the result of.

Here is a working example of how yield works:

```
function* test() {
    var i = 0;
    while ( i < 4 ) {
        yield ++index;
    }
}

tester = test();
console.log( tester.next().value ); //1
console.log( tester.next().value ); //2
console.log( tester.next().value ); //3
console.log( tester.next().value ); //4
console.log( tester.next().value ); //undefined
```

The result is as I expect. Following the example in the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) I see that you can use yield* to use another generator function. In my understanding then I expect using yield with a function should return that function as it's value. Here is my example:

```
function* test() {
    var i = 0;
    while ( i < 4 ) {
        ++i;
        yield function( a ) { return a + i; };
    }
}

tester = test();
console.log( tester.next().value ); //undefined
console.log( tester.next().value ); //undefined
console.log( tester.next().value ); //undefined
console.log( tester.next().value ); //undefined
console.log( tester.next().value ); //undefined
```

Can anyone help me understand why the value returned is not a function? I looked but is there something I missed in the generator spec that forces the value to be a primitive?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I see `function anonymous(a)` four times. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Same here. Working for me on Chrome 43

Comment: I suppose that the `undefined` you saw is the returned value from the evaluation of the `console.log` statement.

The function is returned from the generator: in the second example I also called the function doing `tester.next().value(1)` (chrome 43 also here).

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) on Mac OS X

Comment: @Dario I also tried logging the entire object returned from the next() call and the object returned is completely missing the value key/value.

Answer (score 0):

Got your code to work in [Traceur](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html). Feel free to re-paste and check. Remember to turn 'experimental' on in the options located top-right.

```
function* test() {
    var i = 0;
    while ( i < 4 ) {
        ++i;
        yield function( a ) { return a + i; };
    }
    return "done"
}

let tester = test();
console.log( tester.next().value ); //fn
console.log( tester.next().value ); //fn
console.log( tester.next().value ); //fn
console.log( tester.next().value ); //fn
console.log( tester.next().value ); //string literal "done"
```

Only diff of consequence: declaring `tester` with `let` or `var` before logging.

I am guessing here, but it looks like a bug in the transplier?
Assigning without the keyword should work fine, I don't believe ECMA6 introduces any limitations here. It would break too much.

Here is the transpiled code:

```
$traceurRuntime.ModuleStore.getAnonymousModule(function() {
  "use strict";
  var $__0 = $traceurRuntime.initGeneratorFunction(test);
  function test() {
    var i;
    return $traceurRuntime.createGeneratorInstance(function($ctx) {
      while (true)
        switch ($ctx.state) {
          case 0:
            i = 0;
            $ctx.state = 11;
            break;
          case 11:
            $ctx.state = (i < 4) ? 5 : 7;
            break;
          case 5:
            ++i;
            $ctx.state = 6;
            break;
          case 6:
            $ctx.state = 2;
            return function(a) {
              return a + i;
            };
          case 2:
            $ctx.maybeThrow();
            $ctx.state = 11;
            break;
          case 7:
            $ctx.returnValue = "done";
            $ctx.state = -2;
            break;
          default:
            return $ctx.end();
        }
    }, $__0, this);
  }
  tester = test();
  console.log(tester.next().value);
  console.log(tester.next().value);
  console.log(tester.next().value);
  console.log(tester.next().value);
  console.log(tester.next().value);
  return {};
});
//# sourceURL=traceured.js
```

`.initGeneratorFunction()` is accepting input, but `test` isn't [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) when assigned like that. So it throws...silently it seems. Looks like this is just a transpiler thing, since `let` [isn't actually supposed to hoist](http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/09/es6-part-2/), just that declaring it allows the transpiled code to have a hoisted variable.

**Can someone with more ES6 experience confirm if this is a bug in the comments?** Maybe the transpilers expect a certain syntax, or this is a requirement of strict mode?

**Summary**:

Looks like your understanding is fine, just a quirk of the current transpiler environment. It's probably good practice to declare your variables, Team Awesome (i.e. [AirBnB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#13.1)) says `const` is a good choice!